# Rudin Chapter 3 Exercise 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is about the exercise in [*Principles of Mathematical Analysis*](https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf), in the chapter on sequences and series:

> Prove that convergence of $\{s_n\}$ implies convergence of $\{|s_n|\}$. Is the converse true?

The solutions I find online base their proof on

$||s_n| - |s_m|| \leq |s_n - s_m|$

But in Rudin, the definition of convergence is that for arbitrary $\epsilon$, there exists some $N$, such that for all $n \geq N$, $d(s_n,p) < \epsilon$ for  some $p$. The [solution manual](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%203.pdf?sequence=9) seems to assume that this distance function is based on the norm of the difference.

But suppose I have the following distance function in my metric space:

$d(x,y) = 1$ if ($x > 0$ or $y > 0$) and $x \neq y$

$d(x,y) = |x - y|$ otherwise

then consider the sequence $s_n = - 1/n^2$. Clearly, $\{s_n\}$ converges to 0 in this metric space, but it seems to me that $\{|s_n|\}$ does not.

Am I making a mistake in my reasoning somewhere?

**Edit:** The metric is not right. We don't have $d(-1, -1000000) \leq d(-1,1) + d(1, -1000000)$, for example. Still the proof in the solution manual seems to assume a certain metric which doesn't convince me about the general case.

Comment: You're not making any error. It just means that, with respect to your second metric, the sequence doesn't converge. If you use the standard absolute value metric, it does.

Comment: So the exercise is essentially wrong? Because it seems to suggest that you need to prove this fact in general.

Comment: There's actually a term used to describe two metrics that have the same convergence properties: equivalent, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics

Comment: No, for the problem you're supposed to be using the absolute value metric. I guess its just assumed, if they don't make it clear?

Comment: It's not mentioned, the exercise is exactly as I quote it. Edit: well, now it is ;)

Comment: You say that clearly $\left\{ s_n \right\}$ converges to the zero, but different metrics can make sequences converge to different things. In your example, the sequence doesn't actually converge to anything with respect to the discrete metric. It should be noted that I think you're supposed to be using the absolute value as your metric in this case.

Comment: I edited slightly to say it converges to 0 in this metric space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37245/discussion-between-nikolas-wojtalewicz-and-sam-van-herwaarden).